# Tikz Matrix with Math and Numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am using Tikz to draw an array of arbitrary length $n$. Below is a MWE

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [
    matrix of math nodes,
    nodes={
      rectangle, 
      draw,
      minimum size=\ReservoirCellDim,
      fill=white,
    },
  ] (res)
  {
    1 & 2 & \cdots & n & 5n & \cdots1 \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Cells that contain exclusively math symbols (e.g., $\cdots$) or letters ($n$) are offset from others cells.  If I mix numbers and a symbol/letter, the cells are aligned as expected.  How do I fix this issue?

[image: Tikz Math Mode Offset Issue]

Comment: Has there been a reason for unaccepting the answer?

Comment: My apologies.  It was inadvertent.

Comment: No problem, I just wondered if I should improve something :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can solve this by using `anchor=center` which doesn't really care about the content's baseline and size.

[image: matrix]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [
    matrix of math nodes,
    nodes={
      rectangle, 
      draw,
      minimum size=1cm,
      fill=white,
      anchor=center
    },
  ] (res)
  {
    1 & 2 & \cdots & n & 5n & \cdots1 \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```